# Ubuntu Server 13.10 Saucy Edition hang At boot time during installation with USBDRIVE

Tags: 13.04, server

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 13.10 Saucy edition with USBdisk, I already made my USBdrive bootable and place ISO image file and installation media to USBdrive but when i boot my new PC , I got a blank screen with "MBR" printing on it, Just after 2 seconds it diappear and i got a new blank screen with some weird small white bright rectangular shape at left bottom side.

It hangs at this time and installation stopped, For recognition of problem i am attaching hang screen here, Let me know if is any solution?

My reputation is below 10 so i cant post my Image here.

Comment: Please recheck it No any duplication found, I am asking question for Ubuntu 13.10 Server edition,And above questions is not related to it., Please remove duplication tag here so i can get appropriate answers.

Comment: Is anyone here can remove duplication label from my question?

Comment: you can't able to boot into both the os's.am i correct?

Comment: No you are absolutely wrong, I am installing fresh Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy edition server and installation hang with above problem.

Comment: which software did you use to make bootable ubuntu usb?

Comment: I made bootable USBdrive with command line by help of instructions available here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuServerFlashDriveInstaller

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/106920/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-bootable-usb-drive-using-yumi

Comment: No i am not looking to make USBdrive bootable, I have already USB bootable with me, , I have problem in server installation, Please rectify those..Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11817/discussion-between-pradeep-gupta-and-avinash-raj)

Comment: You say that there was only black screen when boot from usb,so you did some error in making bootable usb.